# Spring kafka - generate diagram

Tags: spring, apache-kafka

We have a microservice landscape, each Microservices is developed with Spring boot. The microservices talk to each other asynchronously with Spring Kafka. Is there a way to get a dataflow diagram generated? So to have a diagram to see which producer is connected to which consumer?

Comment: You're basically asking for what this provides https://hortonworks.com/blog/introducing-hortonworks-streams-messaging-manager-smm/, but no, Spring Kafka doesn't manage any metadata about who is connected to what and where